# Nexus / Jetty doesn't want to start anymore: Unresolved address

Tags: jetty, nexus

We have a Nexus server which worked fine until friday. Nexus was stopped and since we are unable to start it again but I can't figure out why ?

I think it's a Jetty problem. Here is the stack strace:

```
jvm 1    | 2012-08-13 09:31:10 WARN  [er_start_runner] - org.mortbay.log - failed SelectChannelConnector@*:8080
jvm 1    | java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address
jvm 1    |  at sun.nio.ch.Net.translateToSocketException(Net.java:58)
jvm 1    |  at sun.nio.ch.Net.translateException(Net.java:84)
jvm 1    |  at sun.nio.ch.Net.translateException(Net.java:90)
jvm 1    |  at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:61)
jvm 1    |  at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:216)
```

The configuration is (jetty.xml):

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.mortbay.jetty.Server">
    <Call name="addConnector">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
              <Set name="host">${application-host}</Set>
              <Set name="port">${application-port}</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>

    <Set name="handler">
      <New id="Contexts" class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection">
          <!-- The following configuration is REQUIRED, and MUST BE FIRST. 
               It makes the Plexus container available for use in the Nexus webapp. -->
          <Call name="addLifeCycleListener">
              <Arg>
                <New class="org.sonatype.plexus.jetty.custom.InjectExistingPlexusListener" />
              </Arg>
          </Call>

          <!-- The following configuration disables JSP taglib support, the validation of which
               slows down Jetty's startup significantly. -->
          <Call name="addLifeCycleListener">
              <Arg>
                <New class="org.sonatype.plexus.jetty.custom.DisableTagLibsListener" />
              </Arg>
          </Call>
      </New>
    </Set>

    <New id="NexusWebAppContext" class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
      <Arg><Ref id="Contexts"/></Arg>
      <Arg>${webapp}</Arg>
      <Arg>${webapp-context-path}</Arg>
      <Set name="extractWAR">false</Set>
    </New>

    <Set name="stopAtShutdown">true</Set>
    <Set name="sendServerVersion">true</Set>
    <Set name="sendDateHeader">true</Set>
    <Set name="gracefulShutdown">1000</Set>
</Configure>
```

and the plexus.properties:

```
application-port=8081
application-host=0.0.0.0
runtime=${basedir}/runtime
apps=${runtime}/apps
nexus-work=${basedir}/../../data/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus
nexus-app=${runtime}/apps/nexus
webapp=${runtime}/apps/nexus/webapp
webapp-context-path=/nexus
security-xml-file=${nexus-work}/conf/security.xml
application-conf=${nexus-work}/conf
runtime-tmp=${runtime}/tmp

# If this file is present, it will be used to configure Jetty.
jetty.xml=${basedir}/conf/jetty.xml

# Uncomment this to use the debug js files
#index.template.file=templates/index-debug.vm
```

Nexus version is 1.9.2.3

I can't understand:
why it wants to start a connector at port 8080 (while I only set port 8081) and 
what means the address * (and why not 0.0.0.0) ? And of course why it doesn't want to start anymore ?

Thanks a lot for all your ideas!

Comment: if jetty is trying to start on 8080 then the glue between jetty and nexus is apparently having issues, so not a jetty issue per-se..  You can start it up with -DDEBUG=true for more information about what jetty is doing if that helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved!

The file jetty.xml had only the 'r' permission which is not enough: it must have the 'x' permission too. So Jetty was unable to read the file jetty.xml and in that case it tries to start a default connector on '*:8080' => * is not resolvable (I don't know why they used * instead of 0.0.0.0 ???)

So it was a configuration issue.

Comment: There must have been something else, otherwise it's just stupid. Besides it doesn't work. :P

Comment: In my case the problem was that in .xml files a host 0.0.0.0 was apparently treated as specific interface and not as "listen to all interfaces". Leaving the field empty did the trick. (all that assumes that you have wiped your start.ini file and are using jetty 9.0

Comment: This solution makes no sense. jetty.xml file is not executable.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment on the 8080 vs 8081 issue, but as for the SocketException ...

The SocketException: unresolved address is usually due to some sort of host/dns/resolve configuration issue present on your system.

The most basic testcase for java that might help identify the issue would be the following

```java
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

public class AddrTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0");
            System.out.println("InetAddress => " + addr);
            System.out.println("InetAddress.isAnyLocalAddress = " + addr.isAnyLocalAddress());
            System.out.println("InetAddress.isLinkLocalAddress = " + addr.isLinkLocalAddress());
            System.out.println("InetAddress.isLoopbackAddress = " + addr.isLoopbackAddress());

            InetSocketAddress isockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr,8080);
            System.out.println("InetSocketAddr = " + isockaddr);
            System.out.println("InetSocketAddr.isUnresolved = " + isockaddr.isUnresolved());
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Run this, and you should have the output

```
InetAddress => /0.0.0.0
InetAddress.isAnyLocalAddress = true
InetAddress.isLinkLocalAddress = false
InetAddress.isLoopbackAddress = false
InetSocketAddr = /0.0.0.0:8080
InetSocketAddr.isUnresolved = false
```

What's important to note are the 2 lines...

- `InetAddress.isAnyLocalAddress = true` - means that java + OS reports this as the ANY addr
- `InetSocketAddr.isUnresolved = false` - means that java + OS was able to resolve this socket address

If you get an exception during this test, then you have some sort of fundamental host resolution issue on your system (dns, dhcp. vpn, etc/hosts, no IPv4 available, etc...), nothing you do in java, jetty, or nexus can fix this sort of issue.  You'll need to address this (no pun intended) at the OS / Networking level.

Comment: I marked my answer as the accepted answer because it solved my issue. But your answer is really good to find if it works fine or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Jetty was running inside docker container (jetty:9.3.24-jre8). You need to comment out line about http.host in start.ini:

```
#jetty.http.host='0.0.0.0'
```

Network interfaces get mixed up for some reason.